# Is it possible to instantiate objects with variable names, or access variable names at runtime?

Tags: c#, for-loop, runtime

I have quite a few lines of code that create objects and using various parameters with similar object names and constructors.  The only thing that is changing is the actual name of the object variable being created, and the name of the objects themselves being passed in.  Here is an example of code that matches my current setup:

```
BackyardObject backyardObject0 = new BackyardObject(cat0, dog0, goat0, piglet0);
BackyardObject backyardObject1 = new BackyardObject(cat1, dog1, goat1, piglet1);
BackyardObject backyardObject2 = new BackyardObject(cat2, dog2, goat2, piglet2);
BackyardObject backyardObject3 = new BackyardObject(cat3, dog3, goat3, piglet3);
BackyardObject backyardObject4 = new BackyardObject(cat4, dog4, goat4, piglet4);
// many many more BackyardObjects being instantiated
```

As we can see, the names of the object being created match exactly the names of the objects being passed into the constructor.  Is it possible to create a loop that would set all this up?

Edit

I think I might have lacked details that were needed to get a correct answer for this question.  It isn't a question on "how-to" use a loop, or how to add items to a collection it's more of a question to determine if is it possible to create a "variable name" dynamically inside of a loop, while accessing another variable name dynamically inside of the loop provided the information given above (just made up code on the spot).

```
// psuedo code for something I'm asking is possible
for( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    // create BackyardObject with generic name, while appending "i" to 
    // variable name, and accessing other object variables
    BackyardObject backyardObject'i' 
        = new backyardObject(cat'i', dog'i', goat'i', piglet'i');
}
```

While I understand that I could create additional arrays and lists to store objects and then use those, I was just seeing if it was possible to get variable names dynamically.  I wasn't sure if it was entirely possible, that's why I asked the question.  I know that this is a strange question, but got curious after I seen this Objective-C code:

```
// Getting an arrayName dynamically based on loop index
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    NSString *arrayName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"column%d",
        i];
    NSArray *array = [self valueForKey:arrayName];
}
```

Comment: It's called an array. Use that.

Comment: Yes.  The important part of this question is how the data is stored and not so much how you're building `BackyardObjects`.  So... How are you resolving `catX`, `dogX`, `goatX`, & `pigletX`?

Comment: You need to look at a basic control flow tutorial.  Loops are critical to even the simplest task and most be understood on at least a basic level.

Comment: I apologize for not providing more information at first, but please see edit of question above.  It's not how to use a loop, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Objects* don't have names... what you're talking about is *variables*. And rather than having lots of variables with numbers as suffixes, you'd be better using *collections* - arrays, or lists, or whatever. Then you can do:

```
// Or use arrays...
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
cats.Add(new Cat(...)); // Add the cats however you want to set them up
// Ditto dogs, goats etc

List<BackyardObject> backyardObjects = new List<BackyardObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    backyardObjects.Add(new BackyardObject(cats[i], dogs[i],
                                           goats[i], piglets[i]));
}
```

I assume you're fairly new to C# - I suggest you look at arrays and collections in whatever you're learning from.

Comment: in this case, you will need to have cats, dogs, goats and piglets arrays/list as well, in order to have reference to them and pass them to the const. of the class.

Comment: While not new to C# at all, I understand that I could create collections such as lists, arrays and such as you stated and just use a very simple for loop.  I've updated my question, and hope it's more clear of what I'm asking is possible.  I'm assuming not, but seen something in Objective-C code as of late, and wondering if there is something similar in C#.  Thanks!

Comment: @HansGruber: You *could* do this with reflection - but it wouldn't be idiomatic at all. The fact that you've got these variables with numbers as a suffix shows you're already *thinking* of them as a collection - so why haven't you *used* a collection? Where's the advantage in having the separate variables? Using names dynamically like this just isn't the normal C# way of approaching the problem, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yeah, it was more of a question if it was possible, I was just curious after seeing something in Objective-C that I didn't know was possible when looking at code in a book.  What would be the best way to handle the closure of this question since it cannot be deleted since it has answers? It's obviously not a very helpful one, or one that others will probably use.

Comment: @HansGruber: I don't know about that - it's the sort of thing that does get asked a bit. I don't think it's doing significant harm...